How can I select the last descendant element of type?
I am trying to select the last occurrence of a div element in the following table:


td {
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  padding: 4px;
}

div {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
      <div> Don't select this element </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
      <div> Select this element </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



The last occurrence of a div could appear in any of the sibling table cells so I can't use an nth selector.
Of note, the div only appears after a text input.
I've tried the new has() selector, hasn't gotten me anywhere yet.

Isn't that just something like table td div:last-of-type?

@psdpainter, it isn't. There's no type for td div. Instead of guessing in comments, copy the snippet down and try your solution.

See Combining :last-child with :not(.class).... This is similar to combining :last-of-type with :has(). I'm not sure it's possible.

table td div:last-of-type:not(td:has(~ td div) *) See Select the first occurrence of a tag but igoring the hierarchy using CSS for similar.

Thanks @Alohci it worked, this is some great css kung fu, I really appreciate it!
